# How make schedule with filter data?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I make filter for data from сsv file by some condition.

```
a=len(df[(df['month'] == 4) & (df['year']==2016)])
b=len(df[(df['month'] == 3) & (df['year']==2016)])
c=len(df[(df['month'] == 4) & (df['year']==2015)])
d=len(df[(df['month'] == 3) & (df['year']==2015)])
```

For example result:

```
a=10
b=5
c=1
d=13
```

Next, try make graph with this result

```
data = [a, b, c, d]
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.barplot(x="x", y="y", data=data)
```

Error instead of schedule 
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

How to avoid this error and make schedule?

All error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-44-5701e87866b7> in <module>
  5 data = [a, b, c, d]
  6 sns.set(style="whitegrid")
----> 7 ax = sns.barplot(x="x", y="y", data=data)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in barplot(x, y, hue, 
data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, orient, color, 
palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
3147                           estimator, ci, n_boot, units,
3148                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 3149                           errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
3150 
3151     if ax is None:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, 
y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, orient, 
color, palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
1605         """Initialize the plotter."""
1606         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
-> 1607                                  order, hue_order, units)
1608         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
1609         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in 
establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, 
units)
144             # See if we need to get variables from `data`
145             if data is not None:
--> 146                 x = data.get(x, x)
147                 y = data.get(y, y)
148                 hue = data.get(hue, hue)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.  Also, it is very likely that you use the dataframe inefficiently.

Comment: Add all message

Comment: Since `data` is not a dataframe and does not have columns "x" and "y", remove `x="x", y="y"` from the call ro `barplot()`.

Comment: It help but make schedule with one value (it summarizes numbers). How to divide for 4 values?